# How to extract the proper String?

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I have a string like this:

```
 14.809180,56.876968,0.000000 14.808170,56.877048,0.000000 14.805100,56.877220,0.000000 14.804130,56.877338,0.000000
```

i.e, at the  beginning there's a space and also after 0.000000 there's a space. I just want to extract `14.XYZ` and `56.XYZ`. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried String#split() method, perhaps doing `split("[,\\s]+");` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, try String#split(...), such as:

```
  String test = "14.809180,56.876968,0.000000 14.808170,56.877048,0.000000 14.805100,56.877220,0.000000";
  String[] tokens = test.split("[,\\s]+");
  for (String token : tokens) {
     System.out.println(token);
  }
```

`"[,\\s]+"` is a regular expression that helps the split method split the String using one or more white space characters (\s) or a comma.

Comment: While the iteration i just need the 14.xyz and 56.xyz...what should I do in this case?

Comment: To skip the every third iteration i tweaked the foreach loop into normal for loop String[] tokens = coordinates.split("[,\\s]+"); 
            for(int j=1;j<tokens.length;j++){
             if(j%3!=0)System.out.println(tokens[j]);
            }

Answer (score 0):

use [`String.split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to separate each number and then [`Double.valueOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) to convert it to a `double`.

```
String string = "14.809180,56.876968,0.000000 14.808170,56.877048,0.000000 14.805100,56.877220,0.000000 14.804130,56.877338,0.000000";
String[] numStrings = string.split("[ ,]");
for (String num : numStrings) {
    double d = Double.valueOf(num);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will split, and iterate over all decimals in the *input* string

```
String groups[] = input.split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
   String decimals[] = groups[i].split(",");
   for(int j = 0; j < decimals.length; j++) {
      float f = Float.parseFloat(decimals[j]);
      //do something with f
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most beautiful solution, but it will work.

```
String[] myStrings = uglyString.spli(",");
Integer firstNum = new Integer(myStrings[0]);
Integer secondNum = new Integer(myStrings[1]);
```